# Use multiple model in one modelform and save one user input field to two model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So,I was stuck on this for two days, I used to had a view and template that combine the django build-in User model and my own Maker model as below

**Forms.py**
    from .models import Maker,Major,User

```
class NewMakerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField()
    username = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self ,*args, **kwargs):
        super(NewMakerForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].required = True
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','first_name','last_name','email')

class MakerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    #--------------------------------------error part------------------------
    other_major = forms.CharField()    
    #--------------------------------------error part------------------------

    class Meta:
        model = Maker
        fields = ('maker_major','other_major','maker_related_category','profile_pic',)

    #--------------------------------------error part------------------------
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakerProfileForm,self).clean()
        Major.objects.get_or_create(
         major_name=self.cleaned_data.get('other_major')
        )
    self.cleaned_data['other_major']=Major.major_name
    #--------------------------------------error part------------------------
```

**It works fine at first, untail i add a new field and try to let user inpt some "other_major" and save the input to model Major's major_name row**

**Views.py**

```
def NewMakerView(request):
    registered = False
     if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = NewMakerForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = MakerProfileForm(data=request.POST,)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = NewMakerForm()
        profile_form = MakerProfileForm()
    return render(request,
            'boodemo/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )
```

**I didn't change any code in Views.py (or shoudl I?)**

And here's the error code, i don't get it why **Major' has no attribute 'major_name**

```
Traceback:
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/bootsdemo/boodemo/views.py" in NewMakerView
  114.         if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  162.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  154.             self.full_clean()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  354.         self._clean_form()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  378.             cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualproject/venv/bootsdemo/boodemo/forms.py" in clean
  79.         self.cleaned_data['other_major']=Major.major_name

Exception Type: AttributeError at /demo/newmaker/
Exception Value: type object 'Major' has no attribute 'major_name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major is a class. The class itself doesn't have that attribute, only the instances do. For some reason, you're getting or creating an instance, ignoring it, then trying to use a non-existent class attribute. Instead you should actually keep and use the instance you got.

```
major_instance, created = Major.objects.get_or_create(
     major_name=self.cleaned_data.get('other_major')
  )
self.cleaned_data['other_major'] = major_instance.major_name
```

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman thanks for your help! but I got 
`'tuple' object has no attribute 'major_name'`
at same place, and even more confuse now, any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that get_or_create returns a tuple. Updated.

Comment: it works! but still got problem, now the data input by user will save into model Major, but my "MakerProfileForm" didn't, save any data, only the "NewMakerForm" got saved..

Answer (score 0):

SO, at last I figure out how to use multiple model in model form, and how to save it
English is not my mother language so I'll let the code talk

```
class Major(models.Model):
    major_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.major_name

class Maker(models.Model):
    ...
    maker_major = models.ManyToManyField(Major,blank=True)
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**what i want to do here is let a user(Maker) choose a major(major_name).**

```
class MakerProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    other_major = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Maker
        fields = ('maker_major','other_major',...)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MakerProfileForm,self).clean()
        major, _ = Major.objects.get_or_create(
        major_name=self.cleaned_data.get('other_major')
        )
        self.cleaned_data['other_major'] = major.major_name
```

I use the `ModelForm` and `model=Maker`, but than i want to **let user not only choose but can input text to add `other_major` into `Major.major_name`**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
 profile_form = MakerProfileForm(data=request.POST,)
  if profile_form.is_valid():
     profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
     profile.save()
     profile_form.save_m2m()
     major = Major.objects.get(major_name=profile_form.cleaned_data['other_major'])
     profile.maker_major.add(major)
```

At last, save the `maker_major` choice by user, and **add** `other_major` witch is text input by user to `MakerProfileForm`